# How do you count the number of adjacent zeros at the beginning and end of an array?

Tags: arrays, matlab

Suppose I have the following array `r`:

```
>> A=[1:10];
>> r=(A>=2&A<=8)
r =
     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0
```

How do I count the number of zeroes on each side of an array?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to count the number of leading and trailing zeroes in an array.  We can do this with two `find` calls with only searching for the first occurrence of a non-zero element.   The index of the first non-zero element subtracted by 1 will tell you how many zeroes there are that are leading.  The reason why we subtract by 1 is due to the way MATLAB indexes arrays as they start at 1.  Should they start at 0, then there's no need for the subtraction.  If you want **trailing** zeroes, look for the **last** non-zero element.  The amount of elements from this point to the end are how many zero elements there are.  Therefore:

```
num_leading = find(r, 1, 'first') - 1;
num_trailing = numel(r) - find(r, 1, 'last');
```

With your example, we get the following:

```
num_leading =

     1

num_trailing =

     2
```

---

Some more examples for you to show that this works:

## Example #1

```
r = [1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0];
num_leading = find(r, 1, 'first') - 1
num_trailing = numel(r) - find(r, 1, 'last')

num_leading =

     0

num_trailing =

     2
```

## Example #2

```
r = [1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1];
num_leading = find(r, 1, 'first') - 1
num_trailing = numel(r) - find(r, 1, 'last')

num_leading =

     0


num_trailing =

     0
```

## Example #3

```
r = [0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0];
num_leading = find(r, 1, 'first') - 1
num_trailing = numel(r) - find(r, 1, 'last')

num_leading =

     2


num_trailing =

     2
```

---

As you can see, this can adapt to any shape your array can take, provided that it is 1D and a row vector.

Comment: Maybe `num_trailing = numel(r) - find(r, 1, 'last') ` will be faster, as it avoids flipping

Comment: @LuisMendo yes! I couldn't quite figure out how to do it for the end. Thanks Luis!