# How to sum all matrix elements which are lefter and higher?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

Suppose I have a 3x4 matrix

[image]

Now how to calculate a matrix of the same size, which contains each element being a sum of itself and all elements, which are higher and lefter than it?

[image]

Comment: This isn't my question of course, but I did help you answer a question a while back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27630258/how-do-you-count-the-number-of-adjacent-zeros-at-the-beginning-and-end-of-an-arr - Consider accepting my answer if you found it to be useful.

Comment: Thanks @rayryeng! Sorry for the delay, but will select your answer when be ready!

Comment: No problem :) Just wanted to make sure you saw my answer.  Good luck!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must be looking for [`cumsum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html):

```
integ = cumsum( cumsum( A, 1 ), 2 );
```

For example:

```
A = [1 2 3;
     4 5 6];
cumsum( cumsum( A, 1 ), 2 )
```

Results with:

```
1    3    6
5   12   21
```

PS,
This operation is sometimes refereed to as [integral image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summed_area_table).